# How is '\n' encoded when writing to a file in binary mode?

Tags: c, character

How is `\n` encoded into a file written in binary mode by a C program?

In text mode, under Linux, `\n` will be the ASCII value of the line feed (LF) character, and under Windows, `\n` will be the ASCII values of CR and LF characters.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you write `\n` in binary mode?

Comment: to insert it into the file.

Comment: If you're writing a binary file, it's because you want specific numbers in it. Why would you write a character instead of numbers?

Comment: If the compiler compiles printf("hello world");  it is easier just to write those characters to the file.   There is no benefit to turning them into numbers before you write them.

Comment: @EvilTeach But you wouldn't do that to a binary file, you'd do that to a text file.

Comment: nope that is not correct.   compilers put out binary object files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a C program, `'\n'` is always the single character value 0x0a (it would make no sense to have `'\n'` magically be a two-character constant!). If you wrote to a *text file* under Windows, this would get translated to CR LF (0x0D 0x0A). But, if you write to a *binary file*, it will always be written as the byte 0x0A, no matter what OS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

'\n'  which is an 0x0a.

These words here are to make the answer long enough.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the code uses a character encoding set.  That is overwhelming ASCII, but not specified by C.

With `putc('\n');`, the code generated will take the `\` and `n` and form the character encoding of the newline character.  In ASCII, the newline has the code 10.  So `10` or `0x0A` is emitted.

Had the source code been wrtten in something like [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) and then compiled as such, the value written by code would be different.  37?